# setting multiple attributes for enum structure

Tags: c++, attributes, enums

I have defined an `enum` structure like this

```
class myC {
  enum accessClass {
    none,
    forL,
    forM,
    forA
  };

  typedef accessClass AccessType;
  AccessType aType;
};

myC obj;
```

problem is I must select only one member. However I want to select multiple members.  Currently if I write

```
obj->aType = forL;
obj->aType = forM;
```

then the latter will replace the first one.

I want to select multiple items/members/attributes for an `enum` structure.

What should I do?

Comment: If you want to represent multiple values, you will need an array (as you're in C++, you'll probably want e.g. a `std::vector`).

Comment: can you give a snippet for that?

Comment: If you know all the possible combinations that you will use then you make separate entries in the enum with each possible combination.

Comment: @mahmood: http://gimme-teh-codez.com

Comment: why are there no answers with std::bitset?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a [bitfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).

```
enum MyEnum {
    A = 1<<0;   // 0x01
    B = 1<<1;   // 0x02
    C = 1<<2;   // 0x04
    D = 1<<3;   // 0x08
    E = 1<<4;   // 0x10
    F = 1<<5;   // 0x20
    ...
}

MyEnum m;

m = A;             // m = 0x01  (Only A is on)

// Set values by ORing them in.
m |= F;            // OR in field F. Now m = 0x21 (A and F are on)

// Set multiple values by ORing them together.
m = (A | C | E);   // m = 0x15  (A, C, and E)

// Clear values by ANDing them out.
m &= ~C;           // AND out field C. m = 0x11  (A and E are on)

// Test values with AND
if (m & A)
    printf("A is set\n");
if (m & B)
    printf("B is set\n");
```

See "Using bitflags": http://www.dylanleigh.net/notes/c-cpp-tricks.html

Comment: And perhaps also explain how to use these: `obj->aType = F;` clears all other flags, while `obj->aType |= F;` sets `F` and leaves the rest alone.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, but when you know how to use it, it makes a lot more sense, and certainly makes for less ginormous, bloated code.

Comment: I get this error: `error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'myC::AccessType {aka myC::accessClass}' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: I always preferred '1<<0', '1<<1', '1<<2', etc for the bitfield values instead of hex, less error prone.

Comment: @MooingDuck good call. I've done that in the past too, and just forgot. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

An `enum` instance may hold multiple values only as much as an `int` can: that is, *not at all*.

Pick a standard container (`std::set`, perhaps) and fill it with `myC::accessClass` objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent multiple values, you will need an array (as you're in C++, you'll probably want e.g. a `std::vector`).  e.g.:

```
class myC {
public:
  enum accessClass {
    none,
    forL,
    forM,
    forA
  };

  std::vector<accessClass> aTypes;
};

myC obj;

obj.aTypes.push_back(myC::forL);
obj.aTypes.push_back(myC::forM);
```

Comment: Seems unlikely that ordering is required. Would `std::set` not be more appropriate?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Perhaps.  I'll leave that to the OP to worry about!

Comment: By that logic we could just delete our answers and leave the whole thing up to him.. :P